# Import swift library to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing iOS app. using swift library in objective-C. Change module name yes and product module name set app name. but error to import file name. Also set bridge header.

[image]

error:- #import  File not Found

Comment: Did you try import #import "yourProjectName-Swift.h"  ?.

Comment: yes i am tring all these things